# Strongly typing the react-redux connect with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am getting an error trying to type the parameters for my react component. I would like to stronly type what properties will be on the props and state of a component, but when I do so using Redux, I am getting an error when I pass mapStateToProps to the connect function.

This is the component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import FileExplorer from '../components/file-explorer/file-explorer';
import { ISideMenu, ISideMenuState } from '../models/interfaces/side-menu';

    class SideMenu extends Component<ISideMenu, ISideMenuState> {
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    {this.props.fileExplorerInfo !== null &&
                        <FileExplorer fileExplorerDirectory={this.props.fileExplorerInfo.fileExplorerDirectory}/>
                    }
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state: ISideMenuState) => {
        return {
            fileExplorerInfo: state.fileExplorer
        };
    };

    export default connect<ISideMenu, null, ISideMenuState>(mapStateToProps)(SideMenu);
```

So the error occurs on this line:

```
export default connect<ISideMenu, null, ISideMenuState>(mapStateToProps)(SideMenu);
```

and when I hover over the word "mapStateToProps" in that line I am seeing the error:

```
Argument of type '(state: ISideMenuState) => { fileExplorerInfo: FileDirectoryTree | null; }'
is not assignable to parameter of type 'MapStateToPropsParam<ISideMenu, ISideMenuState, {}>'.
  Type '(state: ISideMenuState) => { fileExplorerInfo: FileDirectoryTree | null; }' is not
assignable to type 'MapStateToProps<ISideMenu, ISideMenuState, {}>'.
    Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
      Type '{}' is not
assignable to type 'ISideMenuState'.
        Property 'fileExplorer' is missing in type '{}'.
```

And these are the two interfaces I am using in the react component:

```
export interface ISideMenu {
    fileExplorerInfo: FileExplorerReducerState | null;
}

export interface ISideMenuState {
    fileExplorer: FileDirectoryTree | null;
}
```

Any insight into this error will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this here `(state: ISideMenuState)` should be of your redux store state type, not the component state

Comment: actually there are problems in you code

Comment: @Topsy  there are 10 different signatures.. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-redux/index.d.ts

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When using generics, you are getting the place of interfaces wrong:

**When you declare your React component:**

```
class Comp extends Component<ICompProps, ICompState>
```

With `ICompProps` and `ICompState` are your component's props and internal state respectively.

**When you use connect:**

```
connect<IMapStateToProps, IMapDispatchToProps, ICompProps, IReduxState>
```

`IMapStateToProps` represents what is returned by your `mapStateToProps()` function.
`IMapDispatchToProps` represents what is returned by your `mapDispatchToProps()` function.
`ICompProps` represents your React component props (same as above)
`IReduxState` represents your App's Redux State

**So in your particular example:**

When declaring your React component:

```
class SideMenu extends Component<ISideMenu, {}>
```

Use `ISideMenu` for the props and `{}` (empty state) for the state as you don't use any state.

When using connect:

```
connect<ISideMenu, {}, ISideMenu, ISideMenuState>(mapStateToProps)(SideMenu);
```

You can use `ISideMenu` as both your React component props and the object returned by `mapStateToProps`. But in practice it might be best to create 2 separate interfaces.

In my apps, I usually can't be bothered typing the `mapStateToProps` return object so I simply use:

```
connect<{}, {}, ISideMenu, ISideMenuState>(mapStateToProps)(SideMenu);
```

Comment: But mate this can't be called strongly typed until the 4th generic of connect is in the game - the redux State in it's glory

Comment: agreed, edited. Just providing incremental help, based on what OP had figured out thus far

Comment: Or just go full on generic... `export default compose(connect<{}, {}, any, any>(mapStateToProps))(MyComponent)`

Comment: It gives me the following error when I use this pattern, `Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments`.

Answer (score 5):

Hope you don't mind if I remove some antipatterns from the code above. Please check the comments I've added. Also I've added withRouter to illustrate the pattern better

```
import * as React from "react";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from "react-router";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { compose } from "recompose";

// OUR ROOT REDUX STORE STATE TYPE
import { State } from "../redux"; 

import FileExplorer from "../components/file-explorer/file-explorer";

// interfaces starting with 'I' is an antipattern and really
// rarely needed to be in a separate file

// OwnProps - that's what external code knows about out container
type OwnProps = {};

// this comes from redux
type StateProps = {
  fileExplorer: FileDirectoryTree | null;
};

// resulting props - that what container expects to have
type Props = OwnProps & StateProps & RouteComponentProps<any>;

// no need to have a class, SFC will do the same job
const SideMenu: React.SFC<Props> = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.fileExplorerInfo !== null && (
        <FileExplorer
          fileExplorerDirectory={
            this.props.fileExplorerInfo.fileExplorerDirectory
          }
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

// compose (from recompose lib) because usually we have more than 1 hoc
// say let's add withRouter just for fun



export default compose<Props, OwnProps>(

  withRouter,

  // it's important to read the typings:
  // https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-redux/index.d.ts
  connect<StateProps, {}, {}, State>(s => ({
    fileExplorerInfo: s.fileExplorer
  })),

)(SideMenu);
```

Comment: also the `<div>` in not really needed here.. you can just return null if nothing to render, of course that depends on the layout of the page

Comment: Another anti-pattern is `import * as React from "react";` that is going to break. OP import was better but still broken.

Comment: But you know, I actually woudn't turn a sidebar into a container. It maybe be more logical to turn FileTree into a container and leave sidebar as a presentational layout-component, somehow if feels more logical. Because FileTree does things, dispatches actions and so on. Sidebar merely appears and disappears, why would it have to carry all the load then. Later you may have other components in your sidebar (userbar for example) and the sidebar will becoming smarter and smarter until you'll have to refactor everything. I would do it vice versa

Comment: @ Aluan Haddad , what you are suggesting is called synthetic imports and only works if tsconfig is setup in this way. If you would check the official page http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html you would see that this is how it's done

Comment: I know enough about `--allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for both of us. The TypeScript example is wrong and the TypeScript team is in the process of fixing the compiler to deal with this serious problem. Irregardless, your import change is actually a reduction in quality from the OP (although his compound import is also going to break)

Comment: That's very interesting I didn't hear of that. Could you kindly provide some sort of link to get more info on that? Thanks

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16093 and the plethora of linked discussions, surrounding issues, and confusion. It's really quite extraordinary how much pain this issue has caused.

Comment: Sorry if I came off like a jerk. This is just an ongoing painpoint that's been frustrating for years. It's become tiresome to explain.

Comment: No worries and thanks for the link, I'll investigate in more closely, unfortunately it's already 5 am in my place  Good luck!

Comment: Toward the bottom of that issue there's actually a discussion of the special confusing ambiguities around react so definitely take a look when you have time. Cheers!