# Typing a HOC component connected with Redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-router

In my Route component i have a Layout HOC that have some components as Children. In this HOC, i render the Top and Side bars, and i also connect him to my redux store to get the current user and dispatch the logout action. The problem is i defined my Hoc's Props and put the children as ReactNode, my user as UserType and the logout action as a function. But in the Route component i get a error because a didn't pass the user and the action as props.

My HOC component

```
interface Props extends RouteComponentProps {
  children?: ReactNode
  user?: UserType
  logoutAction(): void
}

const AppLayout = (props: Props) => (
  <Layout>
    {/* <Sidebar {...props} /> */}
    <Layout>
      {/* <TopBar user={props.user} /> */}
      <Content
        style={{
          margin: '24px 16px',
          padding: 24,
          background: '#fff',
          minHeight: 280
        }}
      >
        {props.children}
      </Content>
    </Layout>
  </Layout>
)
const mapStateToProps = (state: AppStateType, ownProps: Props) => ({
  ...ownProps,
  user: state.auth.currentUser
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
  logoutAction: () => dispatch(logoutUserSuccessAction())
})

export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(AppLayout)
)
```

My Route Component

```
class Routes extends React.Component<Props> {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.fetchFields()
    // this.props.fetchQuestions();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          height: '100vh',
          flexDirection: 'column',
          width: '100vw'
        }}
      >
        <AppLayoutContainer>
          <React.Fragment>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={HomePageContainer} />

              <Route path="/login" exact component={LoginPageContainer} />
              {/* NEED AUTH HOC */}
              <Route path="/gerencia" component={GerenciaPageContainer} />
              <Route path="/relatorio" component={ReportPageContainer} />
              <Route path="/exportar" component={ExportPageContainer} />
            </Switch>
          </React.Fragment>
        </AppLayoutContainer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The error i got:

```
Property 'logoutAction' is missing in type '{ children: Element; }' but required in type 'Readonly<Pick<Pick<Props, never> & Props, "user" | "children" | "logoutAction">>'.ts(2741)
AppLayoutContainer.tsx(20, 3): 'logoutAction' is declared here.
```

I'm trying to type the connect function but i'm getting other error:

```
interface OwnProps extends RouteComponentProps {
  children?: ReactNode
  // user?: UserType
}

interface StateProps {
  user?: UserType
}

interface DispatchProps {
  logoutAction: () => void
}

type Props = StateProps & DispatchProps & OwnProps

const AppLayout = (props: Props) => (
  <Layout>
    {/* <Sidebar {...props} /> */}
    <Layout>
      {/* <TopBar {...props} /> */}
      <Content
        style={{
          margin: '24px 16px',
          padding: 24,
          background: '#fff',
          minHeight: 280
        }}
      >
        <Button onClick={() => props.logoutAction()}>Fazer Logout</Button>
        {props.children}
      </Content>
    </Layout>
  </Layout>
)

function mapStateToProps(
  state: AppStateType,
  ownProps: OwnProps
): StateProps & OwnProps {
  // ...ownProps,
  return {
    ...ownProps,
    user: state.auth.currentUser
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch): DispatchProps => ({
  logoutAction: () => dispatch(logoutUserSuccessAction())
})

export default connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, void>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(AppLayout)
```

and i'm getting this error now:

```
Argument of type '(state: { auth: AuthReducerStateType; }, ownProps: OwnProps) => StateProps & OwnProps' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MapStateToPropsParam<StateProps, void, {}>'.
  Type '(state: { auth: AuthReducerStateType; }, ownProps: OwnProps) => StateProps & OwnProps' is not assignable to type 'MapStateToPropsFactory<StateProps, void, {}>'.
    Types of parameters 'state' and 'initialState' are incompatible.
      Property 'auth' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ auth: AuthReducerStateType; }'.ts(2345)
getReducers.ts(41, 3): 'auth' is declared here.
```

Answer (score 1):

So `logoutAction` is provided by redux, not manually by you.

You've marked this prop as required. Typescript doesnt know it's redux component and it'll have this prop passed basing on `mapDispatchToProps` so it's complaining you didn't provide it

In such case, when some prop is provided by external lib (redux in your case) I usually mark it as optional (which makes sense because you don't really control this prop being passed)

```
interface Props extends RouteComponentProps {
  children?: ReactNode
  user?: UserType
  logoutAction()?: void // <<<--- ? added
}
```

Should solve the issue

Comment: is there any way to not use "?", i feel that the idea of checking if its not undefined is not a good one. As you said it works. i'm trying to use the `connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps>` but i don't have any success on that yet

Comment: i tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48292707/strongly-typing-the-react-redux-connect-with-typescript it works like a charm